# Append Row To Each Group in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say that I have database table:

```
| id         | value     | rank        |
| -----------|-----------|-------------|
| 303        | D         | 3           |
| 404        | A         | 1           |
| 505        | B         | 1           |
| 505        | D         | 4           |
| 202        | B         | 1           |
| 505        | A         | 5           |
| 303        | N         | 2           |
| 101        | A         | 1           |
| 505        | A         | 7           |
| 202        | A         | 6           |
| 202        | N         | 3           |
| 505        | N         | 3           |
| 202        | A         | 4           |
| 505        | A         | 2           |
| 202        | N         | 5           |
| 303        | A         | 1           |
| 505        | N         | 6           |
| 202        | A         | 2           |
```

Following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY rank;
```

I get:

```
| id         | value     | rank        |
| -----------|-----------|-------------|
| 101        | A         | 1           |
| 202        | B         | 1           |
| 202        | A         | 2           |
| 202        | N         | 3           |
| 202        | A         | 4           |
| 202        | N         | 5           |
| 202        | A         | 6           |
| 303        | A         | 1           |
| 303        | N         | 2           |
| 303        | D         | 3           |
| 404        | A         | 1           |
| 505        | B         | 1           |
| 505        | A         | 2           |
| 505        | N         | 3           |
| 505        | D         | 4           |
| 505        | A         | 5           |
| 505        | N         | 6           |
| 505        | A         | 7           |
```

However, for each group, I'd like to append an additional row with the `value` column taken from the `id` column so that the resulting table looks like:

```
| id         | value     | rank        |
| -----------|-----------|-------------|
| 101        | A         | 1           |
| 101        | 101       | 2           |
| 202        | B         | 1           |
| 202        | A         | 2           |
| 202        | N         | 3           |
| 202        | A         | 4           |
| 202        | N         | 5           |
| 202        | A         | 6           |
| 202        | 202       | 7           |
| 303        | A         | 1           |
| 303        | N         | 2           |
| 303        | D         | 3           |
| 303        | 303       | 4           |
| 404        | A         | 1           |
| 404        | 404       | 2           |
| 505        | B         | 1           |
| 505        | A         | 2           |
| 505        | N         | 3           |
| 505        | D         | 4           |
| 505        | A         | 5           |
| 505        | N         | 6           |
| 505        | A         | 7           |
| 505        | 505       | 8           |
```

What is ANSI SQL (or most database agnostic) way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would ask why do you need that in the first place. It seems something to be accomplished in an application layer rather than in the database side.

Comment: Your example is not ANSI SQL it only works on mysql -- if you have a group by you can't use a * like that to get columns that are not part of the group by.  Please provide information on how the other columns are selected in the group by.

Comment: how come this is an ANSI-compliant sql ? you select fields which are neither of :group by members, aggregate, derived of the first 2.

Comment: The desired results didn't come from `group by` query either.

Comment: You're right, it should be `order by` `id` and `rank`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a `group by` in the initial set as you appear to want all the rows back:

```
select "id", "value", "rank"
from T
union all
select "id", cast("id" as varchar(10)), max("rank") + 1
from T
group by "id"
order by "id", "rank";
```

And you can do this with `grouping sets` for the fun of it:

```
select "id",
    grouping("rank"),
    case when grouping("rank") = 0 then min("value") else cast("id" as varchar(10)) end as "value",
    case when grouping("rank") = 0 then "rank" else max("rank") over (partition by "id") + 1 end as "rank"
from T
group by grouping sets ("id", "rank"), ("id")
order by "id", "rank";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
SELECT  id,
        value,
        rank
FROM    table_name

UNION

SELECT  id,
        id AS value,
        max(rank) + 1 AS rank
FROM    table_name
GROUP BY id

ORDER BY id, rank;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select id, value, max(rank) as rank
from t
group by id, value
union all
select id, id, max(rank) + 1
from t
group by id;
```